# Forecasting based on model and initial points

Tags: python, machine-learning, forecasting

I have the following curves (N points) based on an experiment. I can't get other curves because of a lack of resources.

I made a rbf regression with sklearn.svm.SVR which I get the best mean squared error with (0.033).
I have to be able, with a *n* initial points I invented, to predict the next points of the curve.

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLtIx.png)

Do you know how I can use the rbf regression model and the initial points as a reference to forecast the *N-n points* remaining ?

I found many subjects on **ARIMA** forecasting but I don't want to forecast the p points after the *N points* I have. This is not really a time series forecasting problem.

I don't how to take into account both reference and *n* initial points.

Comment: Does the n points you generated have any correlation to the initial N points ? What was the generation procedure ?

Comment: Yeah I created them manually to be like the curve but not the same. Sounds archaic method but, the original curve is from measurements and I have to predict the next points from initial measurement points. I will only measure first points and predict the next one to reduce measurements time.

Comment: So, if I understood, your problem is: you have a theoretical curve generated with N points. You got experimental results by measuring n < N initial points of the N points set. Now you want to predict the next N - n points in such a way that they follow the pattern of the initial n points measures but also minimize the error when comparing to the theoretical results of the remaining N - n points. Am I right ?

Comment: You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Given the points ordered by x as: `p1, p2, ..., pN`.

Let `f_theory` be the function that describes the theoretical curve for the points `p1, p2, ..., pN` and `f_experiment` be the function that describes the experimental measures for the points `p1, p2, ..., pn`.

Take points `q1` in `(pn, p(n+1))`, `q2` in `(p(n+1), p(n+2))`, ..., `q(N-n)` in `(p(N-1), pN)` and evaluate `f_theory` on them.

Fit a curve through the points `(p1, f_experiment(p1)), ..., (pn, f_experimental(pn)), (q1, f_theory(q1)), ..., (q(N-n), f_theory(q(N-n)))` using wherever curve fit model you want.